# Data field - search and write value in new data field (Oracle)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, select, oracle-apex

Sorry, I don't know how to describe that as a title.

With a query (example: `Select SELECT PKEY, TRUNC (CREATEDFORMAT), STATISTICS FROM BUSINESS_DATA WHERE STATISTICS LIKE '% business_%'`), I can display all data that contains the value "business_xxxxxx".

For example, the data field can have the following content: `c01_ad; concierge_beendet; business_start;` or also `skill_my; pre_initial_markt; business_request; topIntMaster; concierge_start; c01_start;`

Is it now possible in a temp-only output the corresponding value in another column?

So the output looks like this, for example?

```
PKEY | TRUNC(CREATEDFORMAT) | NEW_STATISTICS
1    |   13.06.2020         | business_start
2    |   14.06.2020         | business_request
```

That means removing everything that does not start with business_xxx? Is this possible in an SQL query? RegEx would not be the right one, I think.

Comment: I dont understand what you want, you already display only who start with business_xxx, your wanted result is the result of you query actually

Comment: Suppose the STATISTICS value contains **more than one** hit on `business_%`: how do want to handle that output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select
    pkey,
    trunc(createdformat) createddate,
    regexp_substr(statistics, 'business_\S*') new_statistics
from business_data
where statistics like '% business_%'
```

Comment: Yes that looks good! The front part is cut off. BUT there is still text behind the word you are looking for. Can you also cut it off?
The searched word "business_" is either at the beginning, in the middle or at the end and always with ";" separated from the other values.

I'll keep trying. You gave me a very good tip. I've only known RegEx recently.

Comment: @smajo: `'business_\S*'` gives you everthing starting from `'business_'` and until the next space, which is how I understood what you want. You might also want to try `'business_\w+'`.

Comment: GREAT!
I just searched and tried in the regextester. But it's that simple. 
COOL

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following `regexp_substr`:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr(str,'business_[^;]+') as result
  2  from
  3  --sample data
  4  (select 'skill_my; pre_initial_markt; business_request; topIntMaster; concierge_start; c01_start;' as str from dual
  5  union all
  6  select 'c01_ad; concierge_beendet; business_start;' from dual);

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
business_request
business_start

SQL>
```